# Simple Delete Query throwing Null Pointer Exception in Java Derby

Tags: java, sql, derby

I am using NetBeans IDE 8.1 and trying to delete a product using the product id in the database. But the I am getting a runtime error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at ambeysofas.Function.deleteProduct(Function.java:220)
at ambeysofas.AmbeySofas.btnDeleteProductActionPerformed(AmbeySofas.java:866)
at ambeysofas.AmbeySofas.access$500(AmbeySofas.java:19)
at ambeysofas.AmbeySofas$7.actionPerformed(AmbeySofas.java:550)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

The Line Number 220 is the Delete Query itself. Following is the code of the function deleteProduct

```
 public boolean deleteProduct(int id){
    try {

        conn.createStatement();
        try{
        stmt.execute("DELETE FORM tbl_products WHERE product_id="+id);

           b=true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.print(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
               b=false;
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
        Logger.getLogger(Function.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        b=false;
    }
    return b;
}
```

The function is called from another file. the code of the part is given below:

```
private void btnDeleteProductActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    // TODO add your handling code here:
     String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Enter Product ID", "Prompt", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    try {
        ResultSet rs1 = new Function().fetchProductByID(Integer.parseInt(str));

        while (rs1.next()) {

            int r = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, rs1.getString("product_name") + " | " + rs1.getString("product_type"), "Confirm Deletion of Product:" + str, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

            if (r == 0) {
                if (new Function().deleteProduct(Integer.parseInt(str))) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Product Deleted Successfully!", "Success!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Something Went Wrong!", "Oops!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

The code generates the exception when the delete query is executed. I'll be thankful if anyone can suggest some solution.

Comment: If you are saying the error is on the `stmt.execute` line then `stmt` must be null - where do you give it a value?

Comment: I have not initialized stmt. it is declared in the class

Comment: In other words, `stmt` is null, of course it doesn't work. Declaring something does not initialize it, at minimum you should replace `con.createStatement()` with `stmt = con.createStatement()`.

Comment: It worked  :) Can you explain what happened. I am  little weak in databases.

Answer (score 0):

maybe just a miss in you query

FORM despite of FROM

Enjoy

Comment: No, I have corrected that. Its not working :(

Comment: You have nullpointer because your object isn't instanciated

Comment: You forgot to instanciate stmt : 
stmt = conn.createStatement();
Have fun ;)